# WSO2 - Messages Logs - Could not add binding: boundMessageRouter=amq.topic

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm facing some errors when I start WSO2 AM. I've already check the connections in broker.xml and master-datasources.xml, it seems ok.

The wso2carbon.log shows the following messages:

```
TID: [-1] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSAndesContextStoreImpl} -  Could not add binding: boundMessageRouter=amq.topic,boundQueueName=AMQP_Topic_throttledata_NODE:643d0d757292/192.168.96.21,
bindingKey=throttledata {org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSAndesContextStoreImpl}
TID: [-1] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.AndesSubscriptionManager} -  Could not add subscription: subscriptionId=eccd9369-1896-416a-9a1e-fd5ccf40c99c,storageQueue=AMQP_Topic_throttledata_NODE:643d0d757292/192.168.96.21,protocolType=AMQP,isActive=true,
subscriberConnection=Y29ub....{org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.AndesSubscriptionManager}
TID: [-1] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.LogExceptionHandler} -  [ Sequence: 916 ] Exception occurred while processing inbound events. {org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.LogExceptionHandler}
TID: [-1] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.kernel.slot.DeliveryTaskExceptionHandler} -  Error occurred while processing task. Task id AMQP_Topic_throttledata_NODE:643d0d757292/192.168.96.21 {org.wso2.andes.kernel.slot.DeliveryTaskExceptionHandler}
```

Does anybody know what is happening?
wso2am-2.6.0

Comment: is this all in one setup?

Comment: It's all in containers. One to database, one to wso2-am and one to wso2-is. @chashikajw

Comment: are there any external message brokers like rabbitmq are running in the same environment?

Comment: No, we don't. Do you think this problem was fixed in version 3.2.0 @chashikajw? Because I'm thinking about update our version since is not in production yet.

Comment: Always better to go with the new version(3.2) if you are about to start. 3.2 has addressed the identified issues in 2.6 and it includes more functionalities than 2.6. Anyway, this is not a bug in APIM. Seems like any misconfiguration or something.